# How to restore the directory tree structure to a branch upon checkout to it

Tags: git

Suppose i have branch master
in the master i created one.c, then committed the changes

then i created another branch called new_branch, and checked into it
then added two.c, then committing the changes

when i checkout to master again, two.c is still present in the working directory

i need a way by which, upon checkout a specific branch, the directory tree goes bach to what it was

in my case , upon switch to master , i want not to see two.c in the currect directory
and if i checkout new_branch , two.c appears again

How this can be done?

Comment: No need to add `Git:` to your question and also start with "this is a git question" That is what tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard` should remove untracked files (like two.c)

Comment: reset --hard will permanently remove the file, i want to hide it from my working directory while in master and show it back if i checkout to new_branch

Comment: reset doesn't affect committed changes. It will delete the file in master, but it will also restore the file in the branch

Comment: then how to restore it , after git checkout new_branch? how to make it show up again?

Comment: git reset --hard again. That said, something is wonky. When i make a temp repro and try to reproduce your situation, git checkout master and git checkout new_branch automatically modifies the working directory to match the correct branch

Comment: no, they do not modify current directory.... when i switch to master , two.c is still there... if i used reset --hard on master and switched to new_branch it is never shown again in new_branch as it should, it is deleted forever

Answer (score 0):

What you expect is the actual normal Git behaviour. When you switch to a branch, the files not in the branch from the previous branch are "hidden." But it is known that sometimes that is not the case. Usually that occurs when the file ( in your case two.c ) is in use, say in an IDE.

Have a look here: [Git not removing files when switching branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885850/git-not-removing-files-when-switching-branch) and here: [git checkout remote branch shows extraneous files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753467/git-checkout-remote-branch-shows-extraneous-files)

Like the answers linked above suggest, try `git reset --hard` and `git clean -fdx`

Answer (score 0):

use this 
in branch A type

```
git stash
```

then switch branch

```
git checkout <branch name>
```

then

```
git stash pop
```

see if it works